# Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

I am just creating an example website template, and am getting this error in the Chrome console:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I am getting a 404 error when trying to load the css/style.css page, but the path seems correct. Below is some of the basic code for the site:

App:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');

app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname:'hbs'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('resume.hbs')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\css\style.css" type = "text/css">
    <title>Example Website</title>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <hr id = 'headerBorder'>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
 color: blue
}
```

Below are what the folders look like, which shows the path. I cannot seem to find a way to fix this. Any ideas?

[image: Website Folder]

[image: CSS Folder]

Comment: just to clarify are you using sass some where ?

Answer (score 3):

This is likely just caused by not having the expected path.

You're using this line here:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
```

So in this case, you need a folder named "static" and inside that folder you can put your css and images. You would be able to link to them as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I tried that as well. Still does not work, which concerns me about the path. I also tried using an img tag with a picture in the images folder and used a very similar path to the style css one (ie ../images/image.jpg) and it still would not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Changed answer. Where is your "static" folder located?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with hbs, create "public" folder and keep your static folders, css,javaScript,img inside the "public" folder. then

```
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Here is the magic, since you told express that use "public"  as a static folder, when you link the files inside that folder, hbs will take "public" folder as the "root" folder. 
So lets say you have main.css in folder "style" inside the folder ""public", "public/style/main.css" directory, when you link main.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

Also, this is the complete setup for hbs in express:

```
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.engine(
  "hbs",
  expressHbs({
    defaultLayout: "layout",
    extname: ".hbs",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts",
    partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/partials"
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all your css inside a folder - call it `static` or `public`.

So  your css is located at `public/css/style.css`. 
In your `app.js`, you would reference static files by:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

The path of the `public` folder should be relative to the `app.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

just make a folder called static. and put your css folder and image folder in static folder.
Don't forget to first make css folder to keep all css files and image folder for all images.
your code:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, **"static"**)));
in this code you are saying express to look at static folder and because you don't have static folder you are getting error and your css and image are not applying on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Sol:
First create a folder static and transfer css folder to static folder.
2.In html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css" type = "text/css">
    <title>Example Website</title>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <hr id = 'headerBorder'>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');

app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname:'hbs'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.static("static"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('resume.hbs')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to change the different slashes as well, but that does not entirely solve the problem. Propably, the bootstrap CSS defines h1 already as well. You therefore need to change the order of the CSS files in your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <base href="/">
    <title>Example Website</title>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <hr id = 'headerBorder'>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adding only `!important` to your CSS does not solve the issue.

Comment: I tried that as well. Still does not work, which concerns me about the path. I also tried using an img tag with a picture in the images folder and used a very similar path to the style css one (ie ../images/image.jpg) and it still would not work. Any ideas? Maybe it is a path issue?

Comment: I replicated your folder structure and with me it just works. Are you by any chance using a server system to test it? I tried it without.

Comment: What do you mean by server system? Very new to this